# Particle colliding completely inelastically with a sphere placed on the floor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rigid-body-dynamics, constrained-dynamics

I'm thinking about the problem of a moving particle colliding completely inelastically with a sphere. The aim is to find the vertical component of velocity of the centre of mass of system after collision.
The sphere is placed on a frictionless floor. The particle is moving horizontally and is aimed above the centre of mass of sphere.

***What i know:*** I know how to do this problem if there is no floor or gravity. Looking at the problem in centre of mass frame, we know that there will be pure rotation about centre of mass of the system.
When we have the floor, the point of the sphere in contact with floor can't have a velocity component perpendicular and downwards(which would be the case if there was no floor).

***What i don't understand:*** I'm not understanding how to incorporate the floor constraint in this problem. The angular momentum won't be conserved about the centre of mass of system because there is a rotational impulse due to normal force at the point of contact with the floor.

***Core Question***:  I thought that maybe the point of the body in contact with the floor has zero velocity component in the perpendicular direction.
But then, why can't the bottom-most point in contact with the floor has a velocity component in the vertically upwards direction? What's the physical principle involved?

[image]

Comment: What (vertical) impulse from the floor would be required for the bottom of the sphere to not accelerate downward?  What happens to the system if that impulse is delivered?

Comment: @BowlOfRed Are you saying that the point in touch with the floor should have zero verticle component of velocity? I don't know how to justify this. Why zero velocity? Why can't the bottom-most point have a velocity component in the vertically upward direction.

Comment: Upward would be fine.  But your diagram shows it would otherwise be downward.  That can't happen and the force from the floor would increase to prevent it.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Exactly. I can't think of a way to calculate exactly how much impulse would be imparted by the floor.

Comment: Without the floor, do you know the downward velocity of the bottom of the sphere?  And the combined mass?  So you should be able to calculate an impulse that would make the (instantaneous) velocity of the bottom of the sphere zero in the vertical direction.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Yes, i have done it. But my question is, why should the velocity of bottom of sphere be zero in vertical direction. Why can't it be vertically upwards. What's the physical principle involved here?

Answer (score 1):

> But my question is, why should the velocity of bottom of sphere be zero in vertical direction. Why can't it be vertically upwards. What's the physical principle involved here?

It can be vertically *upward*.  Nothing would prevent it.

But your question says that (in the absence of the floor), the rotation would otherwise give the bottom of the sphere a component in the downward vertical direction.  This is not allowed.

Instead, as the sphere starts to rotate around that point, the normal force from the floor increases to prevent the motion.  This force will be sufficient to prevent the bottom of the sphere from accelerating downward.

Assuming you can calculate the impulse to prevent the sphere from intersecting the floor, then you can calculate the effect on the center of mass of the system to see what the velocity will be immediately after the collision.

For collisions like this, you can assume they happen so quickly that the gravitational effects are small.  In the limit that the impulse happens instantaneously, gravity doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Are you assuming that during that instant, the vertical component of the velocity of bottom-most point will be zero? I was looking for a justification of this assumption.

Comment: I am assuming that as it starts at the floor, the velocity cannot be downward.   If something happened to try to make it downward (the collision), then forces would arise from the floor to prevent that.

Comment: Let's assume that the impulse in infintesimal time dt is x. We can calculate speed of com after time dt as a function of x. Similarly we can calculate the change in angular velocity as a function of x. Then we can use conservation of energy(energy is lost when particle sticks but the floor does no work on this sytem) to calculate the impulse x. Basically, can we assume that there is a infinitesimal gap between floor and the sphere(forget gravity). Find the angular velocity when particle collides, then use the above idea of "rotating body colliding with wall"